# How do I access data from ElasticSearch in AWS without Kibana?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have been using AWS Firehose, Lambda and ElasticSearch to analyse and visualize Twitter data following this tutorial:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-a-near-real-time-discovery-platform-with-aws/

It works great and I can open the link to the Kibana dashboard and make the plots. However, I would like to display the plots in a custom built dashboard that I will build with HTML and javascript as part of a web app (I will use plotly.js to build plots).

**How can I get the data from ElasticSearch into the javascript file to make the plots? Can I make the plots update in realtime like Kibana does**

**Is the endpoint an API? What javascript packages and commands do I need?**

**Do I even need ElasticSearch or could I just go straight from the S3 bucket which holds the streaming data into the app via a Lambda function? What are the advantages/disadvantages?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [elastic apis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html)

It's just a matter of consuming those APIs with any programmed ReST Client such as retrofit/okHttp etc.

A sample here : http://www.baeldung.com/elasticsearch-java

To implement this in JS , a simple call will serve your purpose :
**Using JQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://<yourElasticHost:port>/',
    type: '<GET/PUT/POST etc>',
    data: 'ID=1', //
    success: function() { alert('done !!'); }
});
```

ElasticSearch includes lots of `search options` and it is `Document-oriented`.
If the access `speed, Scalability, fine tune queries` based on `json dsl` are your requirements then you can definitely go for elastic approach

Comment: Thanks for this I will try it out tomorrow before accepting.